# OOP Java design how to reuse http client

Tags: java, http, oop

```
public class BertClient {

    public static List<Float> encodeText(String text) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/encode";
        List<Float> bertVector = sendPOST(url, text);
        return bertVector;
    }

    private static List<Float> sendPOST(String url, String text) throws IOException {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String requestBody = String.format("{\"text\":\"%s\"}", text);
        StringEntity requestEntity = new StringEntity(requestBody);
        // send a JSON data
        httpPost.setEntity(requestEntity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        InputStream source = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(source);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        JsonResponse json = gson.fromJson(reader, JsonResponse.class);
        httpClient.close();

        return json.bert_vector;
    }

    private class JsonResponse {
        //This class is for Gson to parse JSON response into Object
        //This variable needs to match the key in JSON response, so it's not camel case
        private List<Float> bert_vector;
    }
}
```

This is more of a design question.

I'm relatively new to Java, I wrote this package so that I can import it and use in other places . All I need is just to send a POST request and get response back in other Java files using `BertClient.encodeText()` Thus I didn't think it's necessary to Instantiate this class. I can just call that method. Then I realized that with this code I'm building a new httpClient each time I send a POST request, which is obviously wrong I guess?

The url is hard coded now for testing but later on it will be retrieved by a method in this class, reading in a url I stored in AWS secrets manager.

I'm wondering how I should design this class so that it reuses code and doesn't create unnecessary new Objects?

Please use modified example code on my original code to explain.

Also I'm not sure if my question Title is correct, it's kind of hard to give it a correct name, so if you have any suggestions on that I will make the change.